# ionic plugin for Google Drive

Tags: ionic-framework, google-drive-api

I have some data I need to synced to Google drive from an ionic app. I am looking for ionic plugins I could use for that

Tried searching for useful plugins but couldn't find any. Does anyone know a useful plugin I could use

Comment: No, just use the Web API. A custom plugin would do the same anyway.